# ReferenceError: request is not defined in NodeJS Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, authentication

I am new in NodeJS and I'm trying to work with session. But I am stuck with this error. Any kind of help is appreciated.

**Code** :-

```
var express = require('express');
var jsonFile = require('jsonfile');
var NodeSession = require('node-session');
var router = express.Router();

session = new NodeSession({secret: 'Q3UBzdH9GEfiRCTKbi5MTPyChpzXLsTD', 'lifetime': 60 * 1000, 'secure': true, 'encrypt': true});

session.startSession(request, response, function () {
    // server handler goes here
    // req.session available
});

function restrict(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.has('sessnm')) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
}
```

It shows me the error in this line:-

```
session.startSession(request, response, function () {
```

Comment: I think your `startSession` function should go in some route handler, so that it is triggered only when there is a request, not on app startup.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj -  Like this??                                                                            
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    session.startSession(function (request, response){
    });
    res.render('index', { title: 'Login Page' });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather, `startSession` should be used in a context where a request and response is available, e.g. as middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    session.startSession(req, res, function() {
        // ...        
        next();
    });
})
```

where `app` is your server instance e.g. `app = express()`

Comment: no, my bad - this was the correct api indeed, but it was meant to be used whenever a req/res was available - edited answer

Comment: I think instead of adding it in each single route, you can add it as a common middleware at the top of your file which contains all or many routes. You can use `app.use` for this.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj - If I'll put this stuff in app.js, then how to assign session name and values. cause I'm doing this in index.js route file.

Comment: @YashParekh No I didn't say `app.js`, I said `app.use`. In fact, I meant to say that put this function in an `app.use` block at the top of your `index.js` file, so that it works for all routes in that file.

Comment: @YashParekh I think you would have to use `router.use` instead of `app.use` in your index.js file.